# jQuery scroll then fixed

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a menu load fixed to the bottom of the page ( `position:absolute;bottom:0px;` ), but when the user scrolls, I want it to get pinned to the top ( `position:fixed;top:0px;` ).

Here is my jQuery:

```
var main = function(){
    var menu = $('#menu')

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() - menu.height() ){
            menu.removeclass('bottom').addclass('top')
        } else {
            menu.removeclass('top').addclass('bottom')
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

And here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb2ume6v/)

I have yet to be able to successfully add the top class.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Try using `removeClass` and `addClass`. Capitalization is important.

Comment: @Ninsly changes made, but the class is still not added.

Comment: And don't forget to embed jQuery.

Comment: jquery dont have functions removeclass, addclass but removeClass addClass. I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the capitalization mixed up, as well as you didn't include the jQuery into your JSFiddle. Here's the updated JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tb2ume6v/1/

```
var main = function(){
    var menu = $('#menu')

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() - menu.height() ){
        menu.removeClass('bottom').addClass('top')
        } else {
        menu.removeClass('top').addClass('bottom')
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Interesting, this works on JSFiddle, but not on my localhost, even with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Is the jQuery call being done after you included the jQuery or before?

Comment: no errors in the console, i have the googleapis in the head and my jQuery code in the body

Comment: You need the doctype declaration at the top, otherwise your `$(window).height()` is returning the same height as `$(document).height()`. Add the following to your html document `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
`

Comment: brilliant! I did not know that was a thing

Answer (score 0):

You should also terminate your statements and your first jsfiddle has no js library loading.

```
var main = function(){
   var menu = $('#menu');

   $(document).scroll(function(){
      if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height() - menu.height() ){
      menu.removeClass('bottom').addClass('top');
      } else {
      menu.removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
      }
   });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: JavaScript, and hence jQuery, don't actually require semicolons. That's just convention. Even at that, I tried it but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I do not think your jquery library is loading correctly. Your not getting any console errors?

Comment: The issue was that I did not have a doctype declared